# Can someone please explain this chain rule based derivation to me?

Tags: calculus, matrices, machine-learning, chain-rule, artificial-intelligence

> $$ 
> \text{Loss}(y, \hat{y}) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left( y- \hat{y} \right)^2
> $$
>   $$
> \begin{split}
> \frac{\partial \text{Loss}(y, \hat{y})}{\partial W} &=  \frac{\partial \text{Loss}(y, \hat{y})}{\partial \hat{y}} \frac{\partial \hat{y}}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial W} \quad \text{where}~z = Wx + b \\
> & = 2(y-\hat{y}) \cdot \text{derivative of sigmoid function}\cdot x \\
> & = 2(y - \hat{y})~ z(1-z)~ x
> \end{split}
> $$

[Chain rule for calculating derivative of the loss function with respect to the weights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDuNo.png)

Sigmoid of $x = \frac{1}{(1 + (e^{-x}))}$

Sigmoid derivative of $x = x\cdot (1-x)$

$y$ here is the required output. $\hat{y}$ here is calculated output.

$\hat{y}$ = sigmoid of (input * weight) where input is $x$ and weight is $W$.

The $\hat{y}$ and $y$ both are $1 \times 1$ matrix. Also, input and weight are matrices.
Can someone please explain the derivation in the picture to me? Please.

Comment: Which part of the derivation are you stuck on?

Comment: after 'where z=Wx + b', it is directly written derivative of sigmoid function = z(1-z). but from where that z(1-z) come.

Comment: Let's set $f(x) = (1+e^{-x})^{-1}$. Now it's relatively easy to see that the derivative is
$$
f'(x) = \frac{e^{-x}}{\left( 1 + e^{-x} \right)^2}
$$
But what is not so easy to see is that this is actually equal to $f\cdot (1-f)$, or in other words
$$
f'(x) = f(x) \cdot (1 - f(x))
$$
So I guess this is what is meant by the last line there ...

Comment: What? I don't get it. The thing i didn't understand is how 'd(y^)/dz = z(1-z)'. I can understand the remaining but not this because 'z = Wx' while 'y^ = (1+(e^(-Wx)))^-1'. I haven't read alot about calculus till now except for power rule so i'm not able to understand how this is derived.

Comment: I want to make one thing clear. I am letting that <br><br>dz/dW = dWx/dW = x'<br> and<br>d*Loss(y, y^)/d(y^) = 2(y - y^)<br>based on power rule.

Comment: There's a confusing detail for me too. How is the sigmoid function related to the other functions? Apparently $\hat{y}$ is the sigmoid function, or did I misunderstand? And how is that related to $z$ ? There is the equation $z=Wx+b$, but how is that related to the sigmoid function? The notation is confusing ... I think the last line should say something like $\hat{y}(1-\hat{y})$ instead of $z(1-z)$.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't mean $\hat{y}=Sigma(W^{T}x+b)$?

Comment: What's the source of this picture?

Comment: Whenever I see the Machine Learning tag, I know it is going to be a post about how the notation from some course doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer shoud be...

Let's $$f(w) = \sum^n_{i=1}(y-\hat{y})^2 = \lVert \mathbf{y}-\mathbf{\hat{y}} \rVert^2$$
We know that $\mathbf{\hat{y}} = \frac{1}{1+e^{-Xw}}$.

First of all, please correct me if I am wrong, but I think $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \hat{y}} = -2(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{\hat{y}} )$.

$\frac{\partial \hat{y}}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial \hat{y}}{\partial (Xw + b)} = \frac{\partial (\mathbf{1} + e^{-Xw})^{-1}}{\partial (Xw + b)} = \frac{e^{-Xw}}{(1+e^{-Xw})^2} = (1-\hat{y})\cdot \hat{y}$.

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial w} = \frac{\partial Xw +b}{\partial w} = x$

$\therefore \frac{\partial f}{\partial w} = -2(y-\hat{y})\cdot (1-\hat{y})\cdot \hat{y} \cdot x$

Answer (score 0):

The linked image uses the *wrong* derivative for the sigmoid, and is very sloppy in the way it handles vectors.

Let's use a variable naming convention where 
an uppercase latin letter is a matrix, 
lowercase latin is a vector, 
and a lowercase greek is a scalar 
$\ldots$ and without any "hats" or other decorations.

Denote the derivative of the scalar sigmoid ([aka logistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#Derivative)) function $\sigma(\zeta)$ as 
$$\eqalign{
\sigma' = \frac{d\sigma}{d\zeta} = (\sigma-\sigma^2) \\
}$$
When applied *elementwise* on a vector argument, these functions produce vector values 
$$s=\sigma(z),\qquad s'=\sigma'(z)$$
In this case, it's  more convenient to work with the differential rather than the derivative
$$\eqalign{
ds &= s'\odot dz = (s-s\odot s)\odot dz \\
}$$
The $\odot$ symbols represent elementwise/Hadamard products, but these can be eliminated in favor of multiplication by the diagonal matrix $\,S={\rm Diag}(s)$ 
$$\eqalign{
ds &= \left(S-S^2\right) dz \\
}$$
Define some new variables in accordance with our naming convention.
$$\eqalign{
z &= Wx+b \quad&\implies dz = dW\,x \\
s &= \hat y = \sigma(z) &\implies ds = \left(S-S^2\right)dz \\
r &= s-y &\implies dr = ds \\
}$$
Write the loss function in terms of these new variables.

Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
{\cal L} &= r:r \\
d{\cal L} &= 2r:dr \\
 &= 2(s-y):\left(S-S^2\right)dz \\
 &= 2\left(S-S^2\right)(s-y):dW\,x \\
 &= 2\left(S-S^2\right)(s-y)x^T:dW \\
\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial W}
 &= 2\left(S-S^2\right)(s-y)x^T \\
}$$
where a colon represents the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$\;A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$